# I want to convert string to integer in cpp using std::stoi function as i want to find the sum of distinct numbers in a string(in lowercsase)

Tags: c++, string

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--){
        string s;
        cin>>s;
        string x = "";
        int y = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i<s.length(); i++){
            if(s[i] < 'A'){
                x = x + s[i];
            }
            else if(s[i] > 'A'){
                y = y + std::stoi(x);
                x = "";
            }
        }
        cout<<y;
    }
}
```

And the error thrown is:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument'
>     what():  stoi

Answer (score 0):

The reference says;

> If no conversion could be performed, an `invalid_argument` exception is thrown.

According to my tests, it works when you enter integers. So, you are probably entering a character that is not possible to convert to an integer.

Comment: But how is that possible as the string x will contain only numbers as i'm comparing the ascii value with 'A'.

Comment: @HeetMehta Your check doesn't guarantee that entered characters are only numbers since not all the characters lower than 'A' are a number. You should check if it is greater than or equal to '0' and smaller than or equal to '9'.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--){
        string s;
        cin>>s;
        string x = "";
        int y = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i<s.length(); i++){
            if(s[i] < 'A'){
                x = x + s[i];
            }
            else if(s[i] > 'A'){
                y = y + atoi(x.c_str());
                x = "";
            }
        }
        cout<<y;
    }
}
```

> atoi function worked for me and i used c_str() of string that acts as an array and contains the characters of that of the given basic string plus an additional terminating null character.